# SDL in Visual C++ - where to properly put images used in the program?

Tags: visual-c++, sdl

I'm just learning SDL and I would like to know where is the correct place to put images and other file stuff in?

I use Visual C++ 2010 Express and the problem is that when I compile a program and start it straightly from IDE, it instantly stops because it can't load images. But when I start it by clicking on it in Release/Debug folder, where these images are placed, it is, of course, OK.

It seems that the IDE starts the program from another path than Release/Debug folder.

My question is - how shall I deal with it? Is there a way of setting the location of images directly in Visual C++? I'm asking this question because when I'm unable to start the program from IDE -> I can't use that IDE's debugger.

I hope I explained my situation well enough and thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click on your project with the right mouse button, select properties, on the window that opens, click on "Debugging", notice the entry "Working directory", put there the directory where you want your program to run.

I am used to create a folder called work and put images, sounds, etc, there and configure the working directory to use this folder.

Also, any dlls not in system path must go there for your program to find it or in the same folder where visual is creating your exe.

Also on the same window, you will see the "Environment" entry, you can use it to configure path to dlls if neeeded setting the PATH environment variable, like for example:
PATH=c:\mylibs\dlls\